# FireBase error Parsing error: Unexpected token return

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to do a Push Notifications. so when i deploy  my code on firebase I am getting the following error when I try to upload a firebase functions

This is the error displayed in my terminal :

```
   22:14  warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting
   22:69  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return

   ✖ 2 problems (1 error, 1 warning)

   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno 1
   npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /Users/mac/.npm/_logs/2018-05-17T17_45_54_673Z-debug.log

   Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

The javascript code :

```
'use strict'
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.sendNotification =functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite((change, context) => {
        const user_id = context.params.user_id;
        const notification = context.params.notification;
        console.log('The User Id is : ', user_id);
        if(!event.data.vall()){
            return console.log('A notification has been deleted from the database : ',notification_id);
        }
        const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');
            return deviceToken.then(result =>{
                        const token_id = result.val();
                        const payload = {
                            notification: {
                                title : "Friend Request",
                                body : "You have received a new Friend Request",
                                icon : "default"
                            }
                        };
             return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response =>{
                console.log("This was the notification Feature");
                    });
        });
});
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You have two return:

`return return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response =>{
                console.log("This was the notification Feature");
                    });`

Replace that:

```
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response =>{
            console.log("This was the notification Feature");
                });
```

Comment: I have replace it :

  22:14  warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting
  22:69  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return

✖ 2 problems (1 error, 1 warning)

Comment: Make a new answer to that Promise error, maybe you are trying to use a .then where you cannot use it

Comment: I modified my source code with the log in this publication

Comment: Yea but it is two different questions, not one

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple each then should return a value 

you have to add a return statement like

> return response

copy and paste this code it will work

> 'use strict'
>   const functions = require('firebase-functions');
>   const admin = require('firebase-admin');
>   admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
>   exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}
> /{notification_id}').onWrite((change, context) => {
>       const user_id = context.params.user_id;
>       const notification = context.params.notification;
>       console.log('The User Id is : ', user_id);
>       if (!event.data.vall()) {
>           return console.log('A notification has been deleted from the database : ', notification_id);
>       }
>       const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}<br>/device_token`).once('value');
>       return deviceToken.then(result => {
>           const token_id = result.val();
>           const payload = {
>               notification: {
>                   title: "Friend Request",
>                   body: "You have received a new Friend Request",
>                   icon: "default"
>               }
>           };
>           return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload)
>           .then(response => {
>               console.log("This was the notification Feature");
>               return response
>           });
>       });
>   });